# import error after upgrade to airflow2.0.2

Tags: airflow

Received an import error after upgrading to **airflow2.0.2-python3.7** image. Package seems to be installed, not sure what is causing the issue and how to fix it. Tried to uninstalling and reinstalling the packages but that does not work either.

```
{providers_manager.py:299} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.leveldb'

# packages
apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0
google-ads==7.0.0
google-api-core==1.26.3
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-auth==1.29.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
google-cloud-automl==2.3.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.13.1
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.1.1
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.4.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
google-cloud-container==1.0.1
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.1.1
google-cloud-dataproc==2.3.1
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-kms==2.2.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==2.3.1
google-cloud-memcache==0.3.0
google-cloud-monitoring==2.2.1
google-cloud-os-login==2.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.4.1
google-cloud-redis==2.1.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.37.1
google-cloud-tasks==2.2.0
google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
google-cloud-translate==1.7.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-cloud-workflows==0.2.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug (harmless) in definition of the [google provider 2.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/) in fact:

In `provider.yaml`:

`airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook`

should be:

`airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.LevelDBHook`

This was fixed in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/15453 and will be available in next version of google provider.

Comment: I just stumbled on this error and it helped me a lot.

Comment: So how exactly does this help? How can I solve the problem? I'm afraid don't understand. (Sorry, I am new to airflow)